# How can I ensure my panda plant has enough light indoors?

Tags: indoors, sunlight, office-gardening

I have a panda plant in my office facing west. I thought it was receiving adequate sunlight. However, my panda plant didn't grow very well and most of its leaves very thin and not fleshy.

Does the glass absorb a great amount of sunshine? What can I do to ensure my panda plant has enough light indoors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The amount of light lost through a piece of glass depends on several factors:

- [Angle of incidence](http://faculty.caes.uga.edu/pthomas/hort4050.web/Hort4050/op/op4/angle.html) of the glass to the sunlight. This controls whether the light is reflected or passed through.
- Which component of sunlight you're interested in. UVA can penetrate glass, but UVB does not significantly penetrate most glass ([source](http://www.publichealthgreybruce.on.ca/cancer/sunsense/UV_Radiation.htm)). The component of sunlight that plants generally use for photosynthesis can generally pass through glass at a maximum of about 90%.
- If the glass is dirty, it will not pass as much light.
- If the glass is tinted or coated, it will not pass as much light.
- Thickness and general composition and type of glass.

You're facing west, so you're only receiving half a day's light already. Assuming the windows are vertical, your minimum loss to reflection will be right at sunset when the light strikes the window at closest to 90°. Prior to sunset, every moment closer to noon you lose more to reflection because the light is striking at a greater angle. If you're in a city office building with reflective-coated windows that only get washed a few times a year, then they're almost always going to be dirty and losing light.

If you *are* in an office building (i.e. can't control the windows), and the windows are causing a lot of light loss, you don't have much choice but to relocate the plant to an environment where it can get more light (or get a different plant that is more tolerant to low-light environments). If you are located adjacent to a window, you can try placing the plant in the direct sunlight through the window to see if it gets better.

If you are in a setting where you can control the window (e.g. home office):

- Make sure it stays clean.
- If you have window screens and you generally leave the window closed, consider removing the screens -- these reduce light transmission.
- As noted above, move the plant closer to the window, possibly placing it in direct sunlight.
- Consider moving the plant where it can be in a south-facing window so that it gets sunlight for a longer period during the day.